# What is the shear stress on a cube for a force acting tangent to one of its faces?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, solid-state-physics, material-science, stress-strain

For a force F acting tangent to a cube's face of side length $L$, I expected the shear stress to be $F/L^2$ but my text book says it's $2F/L^2$.

Also it says that this shear stress is equivalent to 2 equal and perpendicular tensile and compressive stresses, how is that?

Comment: What is your reasoning, or attempt?

Comment: I think your book is wrong - or maybe you are misinterpreting the configuration? See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_stress)

Answer (score 0):

1. for the first part, your textbook maybe wrong or you are misinterpreting what it's saying.
2. for the second part, shear stress can be equivalent to the situation when compressive and tensile *stress causing forces* are applied together. This is because the net force would be 0 but the forces may distort the body and create shear stress.

Answer (score 0):

1. I assume that you think the situation is like this :[image]
   when it's actually like this 
   [image]
2. The second question is very unclear. You should write the name of the book with the page so that one could look at it